# Build Error in Android Studio v3.1.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have checked for any implementation mistakes in gradle files or other mistakes in Java code and couldn't find any.
I'm getting this error :

> 'Could not delete path 'C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\BreakTip\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-fa'.'

Why is it trying to delete the path when I want to build the project?
 Is there any solution?

Comment: Just delete the folder named 'build' and rebuild the app

Comment: I already tried doing that , Android Studio simply recreates the path and gives the same error again. @Sagar

Comment: Well that's strange. For me once I delete the folder, then it worked perfectly. Try to File -> Invalidate Cache/restart ->  Invalidate and restart

Comment: Restart Failed is what it shows with a bunch of errors , mostly IoException errors.

Comment: That's really strange. Update our comments in your question, so that someone could help and won't recommend you same things. You can do a last try, Open task manager and kill android-studio process, as well as all java.exe process and try again

Comment: Let me know if that helps

Comment: Tried killing the processes , still the same error. I am unable to understand how killing the processes would help solve the error?

Comment: Sometimes some java process/android studio process holds onto the file that android studio is trying to delete. Killing them will release the file and android studio could  clean it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is problem because of some version, try to update Realm plugin to 4.2.0.

[See: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5521](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5521)

Comment: Are you sure you posted this on the right question? I don't see that the OP mentions Realm anywhere.

Comment: There's no use of Realm plugin in my Project

Answer (score 0):

In latest releases of Android Studio one option has been added to Clean the project.

Build > Clean Project

After this step rebuild project :

Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: Its strange but Clean Project gives the same error.